# Double picture background without adding a class with css

Tags: html, css, background

I am working on this project: http://www.e-pedkelnes.beta.verskis.lt/

Actually what I have to do is to put a background without adding a class. The background has to be white with extensions for the menu and the footer element. It would be easy if it would be only an extension for the menu. Content is of different size and size depends on the elements in the screen. so, it is easy to put a background for the menu, but footer background will always be in a different position just because of the different sizing of the content. If you understood what I mean :), I would be grateful to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within:

```
.foot-outer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E8E4E5;
    border-top: medium none !important;
    left: 2px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

I removed width and margin and that looked better. You should not have them set on the outer elements, only on the container elements.

Does that make sense?

EDIT:

Your HTML layout should be more like

```
<div class='header wrapper'>
    <div class='header'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='content wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='footer wrapper'>
    <div class='footer'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply backgrounds to the wrapper divs, and apply a centred width to the inner content divs.